# Node.js Parsing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, node.js

OK, I am creating a node.js module that will be a simple and fast HTML parser. Basically I want to be able to parse an HTML file for a certain tag, for example:

```
<html>
<head>

     <title><%=title%></title>

</head>
<body>

     <h1><%=header%></h1>

     <% for(var x in object){ %>
         <div> <%=object[x].content%> </div>
     <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I am trying to make several Node.js Modules to help out with a open source CMS I am also building on Node. I know there are a few that do this, but they all seem to be using RegExp and are slow. I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example that you posted looks just like [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com). You can also check out [Jade](http://www.jade-lang.com).

Comment: I used EJS instead of Parrot and it did WAY better on my load test, so I am going to go with that one.

Thanks for the heads up on this one.

Answer (score 2):

- [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)
- [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- [John Resig's Micro templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

There literally are a TON of awesome JS templating options out there.